# Oracle home is missing

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have an Oracle 12c database running in OEL 6.. yesterday due to some OS related issues, my Oracle home software mount-point got erased completely.

The only thing that is left is the pfile and data files. I have got that.
I do not have backups as well.

What are the options I have got? If I just install the New Oracle home and start with the pfile and with the data files, will I be able to start the database as it is?

Comment: What about the redo logfiles and the controlfiles? Do you have them?

Comment: No I dont have them.

Comment: Was the database down when this happened?

Answer (score 1):

With only the pfile and datafiles, you will not be able to open the database "by the book". You can recreate the lost controlfiles with a `CREATE CONTROLFILE` statement (specifying the remaining datafiles), but the next step would be a recovery, using the redo logs, which you do not have.

If you want to try to salvage some data from the database, you can open it without recovering. After you have created the controlfile and your database is in `MOUNT` state:

```
alter system set "_allow_resetlogs_corruption"=true scope=spfile;
startup force mount
alter database open resetlogs;
```

This is not guaranteed to work, the database may remain open or crash immediately/randomly depending on the scale of inconsistency of the datafiles.